# zsh: argument list too long: sudo

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

I've a command which I need to run in which one of the args is a list of comma separated ids. The list of ids is over 50k. I've the stored the list of ids in a file and I'm running the command in the following way:

```
sudo ./mycommand --ids `cat /tmp/ids.txt`
```

However I get an error `zsh: argument list too long: sudo`
This I believe is because the kernel has a max size of arguments it can take. One option for me is to manually split the file into smaller pieces (since the ids are comma separated I can't just break it evenly) and then run the command each time for each file.

Is there a better approach?

`ids.txt` file looks like this:

```
24342,24324234,122,54545,565656,234235
```

Comment: Make `mycommand` read the file itself rather than using the command line.

Comment: Yeah that's one option. I wanted to see if there was a way without modifying the code for the script.

Comment: There might be, but that hacking the script is best.

Comment: Use `xargs`: `xargs sudo ./mycommand --ids < /tmp/ids.txt`.  Since you're splitting on white space with the back-quotes and `cat`, the fact that `xargs` does the same is a benefit.  There are always limits to how big the combined argument list plus environment can be — it is usually at least 128 KiB on Unix-like systems, I believe, and often nearer 512 KiB.  If the IDs are more than about 10 characters long, therefore, 50k of them is too big.  The `find` program also splits command lines automatically with `find … -exec cmd {} +` notation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I get xargs: argument line too long 
Size of my file is 0.82 MB. 
xargs --show-limits output:
`Your environment variables take up 3083 bytes

POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2616309

POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096

Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2613226

Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072`

Comment: What did you actually type?  Or how is `/tmp/ids.txt` formatted?  If the file is all on one line, then you need to split it up into lines — how depends on the data.  Otherwise, you didn't type what I suggested; it 'cannot' (should not) produce that error.  If your input is a single line of comma-separated numbers, then you're abusing the shell and your program — they should be space or newline separated (newline is probably better). You could use `tr ',' '\n' < /tmp/ids.txt` to map commas into newlines. With separate ID numbers in separate command line arguments, your program can do less work!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As mentioned by you, ids.txt is a single line comma separated list. If I create a file with new lines, how would my `ids` field take it as a list of values? I'm using jcommander of java to parse the comma separated values into a list.

Comment: My discussion assumes `zsh` is sufficiently similar to `bash` that the differences don't matter.  Also, on my Mac, it seems that Bash built-in commands (e.g. `echo`) can handle enormous argument lists (I tested up to 16 MiB), but for external commands, the limit is 128 KiB.

Comment: You redesign your program to work sensibly. In this context, you provide it with the file name and let it read the file — you don't try to pass it as a command-line argument list (maybe you add `-ids-file=/tmp/ids.list` option, leaving it to work on small lists as now). Or you redesign the command to accept a list of ID values as separate arguments, not as one single argument (but you still run into problems when the list is too big if they must all be processed in one invocation). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_   If you need a single argument that is too big for your system, you're hosed until you change something — either the system parameters or your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into a semi-coherent answer.*</sup>

The file `ids.txt` contains a single line of comma-separated values, and the total size of the file can be too big to be the argument list to a program.

Under many circumstances, using `xargs` is the right answer, but it relies on being able to split the input up in to manageable chunks of work, and it must be OK to run the program several times to get the job done.

In this case, `xargs` doesn't help because of the size and format of the file.

It isn't stated absolutely clearly that all the values in the file must be processed in a single invocation of the command.  It also isn't absolutely clear whether the list of numbers must all be in a single argument or whether multiple arguments would work instead.  If multiple invocations are not an issue, it is feasible to reformat the file so that it can be split by `xargs` into manageable chunks.  If need be, it can be done to create a single comma-separated argument.

However, it appears that these options are not acceptable.  In that case, something has to change.

- **If you must supply a single argument that is too big for your system, you're hosed until you change something — either the system parameters or your program.**

Changing the program is usually easier than reconfiguring the o/s, especially if you take into account reconfiguring upgrades to the o/s.

One option worth reviewing is changing the program to accept a file name instead of the list of numbers on the command line:

```
sudo ./mycommand --ids-list=/tmp/ids.txt
```

and the program opens and reads the ID numbers from the file.  Note that this preserves the existing `--ids …comma,separated,list,of,IDs` notation.  The use of the `=` is optional; a space also works.

Indeed, many programs work on the basis that arguments provided to it are file names to be processed (the Unix filter programs — think `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, `cat`, …), so simply using:

```
sudo ./mycommand /tmp/ids.txt
```

might be sufficient, and you could have multiple files in a single invocation by supplying multiple names:

```
sudo ./mycommand /tmp/ids1.txt /tmp/ids2.txt /tmp/ids3.txt …
```

Each file could be processed in turn.  Whether the set of files constitutes a single batch operation or each file is its own batch operation depends on what `mycommand` is really doing.